# Contents of virtual disk on SAN appear different on multiple hosts

Tags: storage-area-network

I have a Dell MD3200i SAN device and a virtual disk configured.

Two Windows host servers connect to this virtual disk via iSCSI.

Changes made to the virtual disk on one host do not immediately replicate over to the other - it can take hours.  This makes no sense to me as it's the same virtual disk.

Is this by design, why, and is there a way of preventing the delay in changes appearing on the other host?

- Host 1 - Windows Server 2012 member server with Hyper-V role
  installed
- Host 2 - Windows Server 2008 R2 member server

Each server has a dedicated network connection to the SAN device.

I am testing by simply creating folders on the virtual disk from the Windows host, creating Notepad documents, deleting folders and files.  If I delete a file, I can still access it on the other host.

Comment: Can you explain your infrastructure a little bit more. Are these Hyper-V hosts? How are you testing changes?

Comment: Sure thing - have updated.

Answer (score 8):

Windows Servers are not designed to be connected to shared storage at the same time. They just aren't SAN aware in that context and will expect (and presume) total ownership of block level storage.

There are exceptions (Hyper-V using Cluster Shared Volumes) but these are specific use cases with specific requirements.

So, in other words, your testing is moot really and you're destined for data corruption. I wouldn't go as far as to say it's working as expected, but it's not really expected to work at all.

Comment: Double-plus correct. The proper way to share a single volume between Windows machines is to use a network file share, like SMB or NFS - not a block-storage presentation protocol like iSCSI. Actually sharing the disks for simultaneous access will be a disaster, as you're starting to find out.

Comment: Incorrect. The Dell MD3200i is fully capable of having multiple hosts connected to the same virtual disk. That is the point of having virtual disk groups.  Site is useless as ever :| Dan, I appreciate the time to answer, thanks.

Comment: @Kez It's nothing to do with what your SAN is capable of - it's a limitation of Windows.

Comment: Having two computers writing to the same iSCSI target is just asking to lose all your data. Or maybe getting down on your knees and begging to lose all your data. How does the Dell MD3200i handle this?

Comment: @Kez - You're correct in that the MD3200i is fully capable of having multiple hosts connected to the same virtual disk, but actually doing that is predicated on the ability of the host OS to handle multiple host access to that virtual disk, which is accomplished via a clustered/cluster aware file system, such as VMFS or CSVFS.

Comment: Kez - Joe (and Dan and Michael Hampton) are right on the money with this. The storage unit can do it, and you're doing it. You're doing it with a bad choice of filesystem though, it will gladly let you shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Here's something right from page 57 of the admin guide : "All hosts in a host group must have the same host type (operating system). In addition, all hosts in the host group must 
have special software, such as clustering software, to manage virtual disk sharing and accessibility." ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/Common/powervault-md3660i_Administrator%20Guide_en-us.pdf

Comment: So, not to flood you with multiple comments, but you could do this a few ways : make a new disk, attach it to one server, and then share it out via Windows File Sharing (SMB) to the other server. Or, you could install Windows Clustering (but I think you need the same OS on both nodes), and attach the storage as a clustered volume. Then, the two servers will coordinate who owns it and won't stomp on each other, but only one at a time will have it. Or, get a storage unit that serves SMB natively, it doesn't look like your Dell does that.